# Why won't my component re-render when I use a redirect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I'm taring authentication in React using Laravel API and everything works perfectly except for some router problems.

I'm conditionally rendering a redirect like this:

```
if (this.state.redirect) {
         return <Redirect to="/home" />;
         }
         const login = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");
         if (login) {
           return <Redirect to="/home" />;
           
        }
```

**App.js**

```
    export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let navLink = (
      <div className="Tab">
        <NavLink to="/sign-in" activeClassName="activeLink" className="signIn">
          Sign In
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="activeLink" className="signUp">
          Sign Up
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    );
    const login = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {login ? (
          <Router>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Signup}></Route>
            <Route path="/sign-in" component={Signin}></Route>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home}></Route>
          </Router>
        ) : (
          <Router>
            {navLink}
            <Route exact path="/" component={Signup}></Route>
            <Route path="/sign-in" component={Signin}></Route>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home}></Route>
          </Router>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Signin.js**

```
export default class Signin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      msg: "",
      isLoading: false,
      redirect: false,
      errMsgEmail: "",
      errMsgPwd: "",
      errMsg: "",
    };
  }
  onChangehandler = (e) => {
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    let data = {};
    data[name] = value;
    this.setState(data);
  };

  onSignInHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/api/user-login", {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        if (response.data.status === 200) {
            localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true);
            localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(response.data.data));
          this.setState({
            msg: response.data.message,
            redirect: true,
          }); 
        }
        if (
          response.data.status === "failed" &&
          response.data.success === undefined
        ) {
          this.setState({
            errMsgEmail: response.data.validation_error.email,
            errMsgPwd: response.data.validation_error.password,
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ errMsgEmail: "", errMsgPwd: "" });
          }, 2000);
        } else if (
          response.data.status === "failed" &&
          response.data.success === false
        ) {
          this.setState({
            errMsg: response.data.message,
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ errMsg: "" });
          }, 2000);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
   if (this.state.redirect) {
     return <Redirect to="/home" />;
     }
     const login = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");
     if (login) {
       return <Redirect to="/home" />;
       
    }
    const isLoading = this.state.isLoading;
    return (
      <div>
        <Form className="containers">
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="email">Email id</Label>
            <Input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Enter email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.onChangehandler}
            />
            <span className="text-danger">{this.state.msg}</span>
            <span className="text-danger">{this.state.errMsgEmail}</span>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="password">Password</Label>
            <Input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Enter password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.onChangehandler}
            />
            <span className="text-danger">{this.state.errMsgPwd}</span>
          </FormGroup>
          <p className="text-danger">{this.state.errMsg}</p>
          <Button
            className="text-center mb-4"
            color="success"
            onClick={this.onSignInHandler}
          >
            Sign In
            {isLoading ? (
              <span
                className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm ml-5"
                role="status"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
            ) : (
              <span></span>
            )}
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Signup.js**

```
export default class Signup extends Component {
  userData;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      signupData: {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        password: "",
        isLoading: "",
      },
      msg: "",
    };
  }

  onChangehandler = (e, key) => {
    const { signupData } = this.state;
    signupData[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ signupData });
  };
  onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/api/user-signup", this.state.signupData)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        if (response.data.status === 200) {
          this.setState({
            msg: response.data.message,
            signupData: {
              name: "",
              email: "",
              phone: "",
              password: "",
            },
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ msg: "" });
          }, 2000);
        }

        if (response.data.status === "failed") {
          this.setState({ msg: response.data.message });
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ msg: "" });
          }, 2000);
        }
      });
  };
  render() {
    const isLoading = this.state.isLoading;
    return (
      <div>
        <Form className="containers shadow">
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="name">Name</Label>
            <Input
              type="name"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Enter name"
              value={this.state.signupData.name}
              onChange={this.onChangehandler}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="email">Email id</Label>
            <Input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Enter email"
              value={this.state.signupData.email}
              onChange={this.onChangehandler}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="phone">Phone Number</Label>
            <Input
              type="phone"
              name="phone"
              placeholder="Enter phone number"
              value={this.state.signupData.phone}
              onChange={this.onChangehandler}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="password">Password</Label>
            <Input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Enter password"
              value={this.state.signupData.password}
              onChange={this.onChangehandler}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <p className="text-white">{this.state.msg}</p>
          <Button
            className="text-center mb-4"
            color="success"
            onClick={this.onSubmitHandler}
          >
            Sign Up
            {isLoading ? (
              <span
                className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm ml-5"
                role="status"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
            ) : (
              <span></span>
            )}
          </Button>
          <Link to="/sign-in" className="text-white ml-5">I'm already member</Link>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is that the {navLink} component still rendered in both cases logged in or not!! but when I refresh the page manually it goes!

**Imgs**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You sould use `history.push()` after submiting form for rerender but my answer is the best idea for making protected route .

Comment: I used history.push() before submitted my question and didn't solve the probleme

Comment: can u make sandbox from your codes ? ill help you fix this.

Comment: i tried but have some problem with I'm sorry kinda new in react! but I used this tuto :https://programmingfields.com/react-login-and-registration-app-using-laravel-7-api/

Comment: So let me make it for you!

Comment: this will be nice of u :)

Comment: check example from my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some experience on this, so ill share it for you maybe helps you.

**Make a protected root**

```
export const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
  let redirectPath = "";
  if (!localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn")) {
    redirectPath = props.authenticationPath;
  }

  if (redirectPath) {
    const renderComponent = () => <Redirect to={{ pathname: redirectPath }} />;
    return <Route {...props} component={renderComponent} render={undefined} />;
  } else {
    return <Route {...props} />;
  }
};
```

**Use it like this on router component :**

```
<ProtectedRoute
     exact
     path="/profile"
     component={Profile}
     restrictedPath="/profile"
     authenticationPath="/login"
/>
```

**After submit login form or signup form**

```
history.push("/profile")
```

I did make Small example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-waterfall-pnrgd?file=/src/App.js) with all of you need for start, Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you brother for your effort I really appreciate u!

Comment: @WrakAli No problem bro, happy to help you.